# Are there any differences between using StringTokenizer and concatenating Strings together?

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I am using Java to make an Uno game. I have a method called `findCard(String cardname)` whose function is to find the card in a hand of cards when the user writes in the name of the card (e.g: “Red 6”) and to return null if it can’t find the card. It works fine when I tried something like:

```
String card = "Red" + " " + "6";
pHand.findCard(card); // return the card Red 6
```

However, in the game, I will need the user to write a full command such as “deal Red 6”. Thus, I use `StringTokenizer` to separate  the card’s name from the command:

```
StringTokenizer scan = new StringTokenizer(input);
String cmd = scan.nextToken(); // = "deal"
String color = scan.nextToken(); // = "Red"
String card = color + " " + scan.nextToken(); // = "Red 6"
```

What is wrong is when I try `pHand.findCard(card);` in this scenario, it only returns null no matter what was typed in.
All I know about `StringTokenizer` is that it can split words in a string so I don't see how these are different. Thus, it would be great if anyone can point out the reason and the solution for this.

Comment: color + scan.nextToken() will result in "Red6" (notice no space). Try color + " " + scan.nextToken().

Comment: [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) might be a lot easier to manage.

Comment: Ah, I missed the space when I wrote this, but in my code, I had the white space between ``color`` and ``scan.nextToken()`` and it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The comments already have the solutions really... but to wrap some more advice around it:

### Your Problem

You're just missing a space between the color and number.

### General Advice

1. Make sure everything is the same case before comparing (e.g. all lower/upper).
2. Get rid of white space when handling tokens.
3. Keep variables separate; card value and card color are both unique and useful, putting them back in one string makes them less useful and harder to use and can introduce errors like yours.

### Recommendation

Modify findCard() to take 2 strings, one with the card value and one with the color.  Also, if you're using "red 6" as a key in a map or something, either:

1. Make sure you build "red 6" from "red" and "6" using a function that you use everywhere you do this.  That way you can unit test the function and you're sure that you don't add a space in one spot and forget it in another spot.  Generally anywhere where you duplicate code, you might mess up - so don't duplicate.
2. Make "card" a class and override equals and hash code to use both of these values when determining equality.  Then you can use card as the key in a map fine.

Also, I kind of agree with the person who said that string spit() would be easier (just because you see it more often in code).  But both should work if you're comfortable; so do it your way if you're happy :).

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that white space when I wrote the question. In the code, I included it, but the method did not work either :( But your recommendations are really helpful, so I will try them out.
Yeah, I agree that I can use ``split()``, but ``StringTokenizer`` is what my professor wants me to use so... :D